# Send file via curl to plupload chunked

Tags: php, curl, plupload

One of my client needs a file(image) to be sent to plupload php script via curl(php-curl) 
. The problem is that file seems should be sent with chunks.

Can you please hint me how to send the file with php to this script?

Here is the file of upload script which accepts the file.

```
    <?php
/**
 * upload.php
 *
 * Copyright 2009, Moxiecode Systems AB
 * Released under GPL License.
 *
 * License: http://www.plupload.com/license
 * Contributing: http://www.plupload.com/contributing
 */

// HTTP headers for no cache etc
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

// Settings
$targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";
//$targetDir = 'uploads';

$cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
$maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds

// 5 minutes execution time
@set_time_limit(5 * 60);

// Uncomment this one to fake upload time
// usleep(5000);

// Get parameters
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
$fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : '';

// Clean the fileName for security reasons
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '_', $fileName);

// Make sure the fileName is unique but only if chunking is disabled
if ($chunks < 2 && file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName)) {
    $ext = strrpos($fileName, '.');
    $fileName_a = substr($fileName, 0, $ext);
    $fileName_b = substr($fileName, $ext);

    $count = 1;
    while (file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b))
        $count++;

    $fileName = $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b;
}

$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir))
    @mkdir($targetDir);

// Remove old temp files    
if ($cleanupTargetDir) {
    if (is_dir($targetDir) && ($dir = opendir($targetDir))) {
        while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

            // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
            if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge) && ($tmpfilePath != "{$filePath}.part")) {
                @unlink($tmpfilePath);
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    } else {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
}   

// Look for the content type header
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"];

if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];

// Handle non multipart uploads older WebKit versions didn't support multipart in HTML5
if (strpos($contentType, "multipart") !== false) {
    if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        // Open temp file
        $out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
        if ($out) {
            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            $in = @fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

            if ($in) {
                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                    fwrite($out, $buff);
            } else
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
            @fclose($in);
            @fclose($out);
            @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
} else {
    // Open temp file
    $out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
    if ($out) {
        // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
        $in = @fopen("php://input", "rb");

        if ($in) {
            while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                fwrite($out, $buff);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');

        @fclose($in);
        @fclose($out);
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
}

// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
}

die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');
```

Comment: " The problem is that file seems should be sent with chunks."
This statement is not clear. Is it a client requirement to be able to send the file chunked? Or, do you think the php scripts expects the file to be chunked ? The chunking is optional. Have you tried posting a file with php-curl ? what problems do you encounter ?

Comment: dear @jbl maybe question is dumb, but it seems the script expects that it will be chunked, no?  I am not very super in php...  I will try to post it as a whole...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented the following lines of the php script, where chunking seems to be involved. You will see that the whole file case is included as default case, when the request chunking parameters are not present.

```
// $chunk is the index of the chunk being uploaded. 
// Considered as 0 if not present in the request (whole file, or fist chunk in chunking mode)
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;

// $chunks is the number of upload chunks. 
// Considered as 0 (whole file, no chunking) if not present in the request
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;

 // if handling the first chunk (or whole file) open temp file in create mode, else in append mode
 $out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");

// if not in chunking mode (!$chunks) or finished processing last chunk, rename the temp file to target nam
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1)
```

Hope this will help

According to your comments, the current page should post the file, with file name defaultname.txt

```
<html> 
  <head> 
   <title>Upload Form</title> 
   </head> 
<body> 
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload.php"; method="POST"> 
    <input type="text" name="name" size="20" value="defaultname.txt"/> <br /><br /> 
    <input type="file" name="file" size="20" /> <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="upload" /> 
 </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Did I understood correct? If i make a POST a file with variable name "name" fully, it should work, right? (problem is that we have no right to edit the upload.php script)

Comment: @MR.GEWA "name" is just the name of the file. The file content must be included too. See http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/

Comment: when i post a real file i get {"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}

Comment: I have added Network Tool Data for the usual post, which works. @jbl

Comment: last thing. Could you remove action="XXXXX" part of your answer where we can see the host?